# break a for loop without resetting its index in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

```
no_elements = int(input())
seq = list(map(int, input().split()))
new_seq = []
diff = []
diff_opp = []

new_seq.append(seq[0])

for element in range(no_elements - 1):
    diff.append(seq[element + 1] - seq[element])

for element in range(no_elements - 1):
    diff[element] = -diff[element]


for diff_element in range(0, len(diff)):
    print(diff_element)
    for i in range(4):
            print(i)
            new_seq.append(diff[diff_element] + new_seq[i])
            break


print(new_seq)
```

Actually, I want that my nested (2nd) loop should do its work only 1 time and break every time it does so, plus I also want that value of i is not reset every time i say break as i am working with a list (new_seq) and in that I don't want to the same work with same number, instead i want that value of i doesn't change and i can do the logic with the whole list.

BTW I want to calculate the difference between each 2 elements in the list and then find its inverse(inverse of sign) and find a new sequence starting with the first element of the original sequence.

[image]

**This is the actual question.☝**

Comment: It would be helpful if you would add some expected input and output to make it more clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Exactly, do not use input(), but just explicitly give the numbers as an example, and give the expected output as well. Your question is not clear in this way

Comment: please see my edited question

Comment: If you want an unreadable one-liner using the stdlib's `functools.reduce` you could use `reduce(lambda x, y: x + [x[-1] + y], [-(j - i) for i, j in zip(seq[:-1], seq[1:])], [seq[0]])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited my first answer based on your new information

```
seq = [-321, 524, 12, 0, 924, -658, -2]
diff = list()

for ii, element in enumerate(seq[1:]):
    diff.append(-(element - seq[ii]))

new_value = seq[0]
new_seq = [new_value]
for value in diff:
    new_value += value
    new_seq.append(new_value)

print(seq)
print(diff)
print(new_seq)
```

This will give the output

```
[-321, 524, 12, 0, 924, -658, -2]
[-845, 512, 12, -924, 1582, -656]
[-321, -1166, -654, -642, -1566, 16, -640]
```

The output corresponds with your example

For completeness, also the numpy version:

```
import numpy as np
seq = np.array([-321, 524, 12, 0, 924, -658, -2])
diff = -np.diff(seq)
new_seq = np.cumsum(np.hstack([seq[0], diff]))
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped. Will learn numpy when I get time seems really simple.

Comment: Learning numpy is definitely worth your time. As I mentioned before, numerical operation run about 100 x times faster using numpy compared to pure Python. In this particular case the running time is probably slower since it takes time to load the module, but for larger arrays this is easily compensated. The often heart argument that Python is slow is nonsense when you use Numpy: it is as fast as C because it is largely written in C

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want to run only once cycle of inner loop and keep index i for the next iteration?

```
diff[0] + new_seq[0]
diff[1] + new_seq[1]
diff[2] + new_seq[2]
diff[3] + new_seq[3]
diff[4] + new_seq[0]  <- reset i
..
```

Then:

```
i = -1
for element in diff:
    i = (i + 1) % 4
    new_seq.append(element + new_seq[i])
```

Another possible interpretation is that you want

```
diff[0] + new_seq[0]
diff[1] + new_seq[0]
diff[2] + new_seq[0]
..
diff[0] + new_seq[1]
diff[1] + new_seq[1]
..
```

In this case you would need to flip cycles:

```
for i in range(4):
    for element in diff:
        new_seq.append(element + new_seq[i])
```